# DirectX9 Texture of arbitrary size (non 2^n)

Tags: c++, directx, textures

I'm relatively new to DirectX and have to work on an existing C++ DX9 application. The app does tracking on a camera images and displays some DirectDraw (ie. 2d) content. The camera has an aspect ratio of 4:3 (always) and the screen is undefined.

I want to load a texture and use this texture as a mask, so tracking and displaying of the content only are done within the masked area of the texture. Therefore I'd like to load a texture that has exactly the same size as the camera images.

I've done all steps to load the texture, but when I call `GetDesc()` the fields `Width` and `Height` of the `D3DSURFACE_DESC` struct are of the next bigger power-of-2 size. I do not care that the actual memory used for the texture is optimized for the graphics card but I did not find any way to get the dimensions of the original image file on the harddisk.

I do (and did, but with no success) search a possibility to load the image into the computers RAM only (graphicscard is not required) without adding a new dependency to the code. Otherwise I'd have to use OpenCV (which might anyway be a good idea when it comes to tracking), but at the moment I still try to avoid including OpenCV.

thanks for your hints,
Norbert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172802(VS.85).aspx) with parameters 3 and 4 being

```
D3DX_DEFAULT_NONPOW2.
```

After that, you can use

```
D3DSURFACE_DESC Desc;
m_Sprite->GetLevelDesc(0, &Desc);
```

to fetch the height & width.

Comment: This will work if the device supports non-power of 2 sizes (nearly all do, as far as I know).

Comment: Well, older cards probably do not. But nearly all recent cards do.

Comment: Actually the width and height will be in the D3DXIMAGE_INFO if you pass one as the __3rd last__ parameter to D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx

Answer (score 1):

[D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172867.aspx) may be what you are looking for.

I'm assuming you are using D3DX because I don't think Direct3D automatically resizes any textures.