# Please recommend a 2D animation c++ tool for XP, Win7, and Win8

Tags: c++, animation, directx, 2d, direct3d

I am working on a c++ project dealing with 2D animations involving high resolution png pictures. I want the program to be compatible with all popular windows editions: XP, Vista, 7, and 8.

The first thing I've tried is the legacy GDI/GDI+, with which the animations cannot run smoothly. Besides, they are said to be abandoned in the future.

Then I examined DirectX. The D2D looks tempting but not supported by XP. Its predecessor DirectDraw is a legacy stuff to be abandoned. The D3D in DX9.0 is said to be able to work with 2D. I followed the instruction on a webpage to draw pictures with Direct3D Sprites. The pictures, however are disproportionate. I debug it the whole night only to find textures are automatically scaled to make height and width some power of 2 (DX is completely new to me :( ). I don't want the scale.

I am not sure whether it is correct that D2D utilizes the D3D interface. If so, I think there must be some better ways to use D3D for 2D application. But I cannot find it. So please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectX 9 can handle non power of two textures, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187157/directx9-texture-of-arbitrary-size-non-2n)

So it should not be a problem to use DirectX 9 at all.

Otherwise you can also look at OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, is it true that some hardware requires a power of 2? Or just very old one that I can ignore?

Comment: @LeOpArD you can pretty much ignore, very old hardware only

Answer (score 0):

I haven't you used my self, but you can take a look on Qt's [Graphics View](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html) in conjunction with the [Animation Framework](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/animation-overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at SDL: http://www.libsdl.org/
It is commonly used for games. You might be able to find a lot of tutorials out there for it. It will also be a bit higher level than DirectX and so might be easier to ramp up on.